# Django FileField how to get real temp uploaded file path?

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a new class for file field to upload selected file on server through FTP. When in method `pre_save()`, I'm trying to get file path this is raising below error:

```
The 'auth_img' attribute has no file associated with it.
```

**Here is my class:**

```
class XFileField(FileField):

    attr_class = FieldFile
    descriptor_class = FileDescriptor
    description = _("File")

    def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, name=None, upload_to='', **kwargs):
        self._unique_set_explicitly = 'unique' in kwargs
        self._primary_key_set_explicitly = 'primary_key' in kwargs

        if 'ext_whitelist' in kwargs:
            ext_whitelist = kwargs.pop('ext_whitelist')
            self.ext_whitelist = [i.lower() for i in ext_whitelist]

        super(XFileField, self).__init__(verbose_name, name, upload_to, **kwargs)

    def pre_save(self, model_instance, add):
        file_ = super(XFileField, self).pre_save(model_instance, add)

        if file_ is not None:
            file_.save(file_.name, file_, save=True)  # Raising Error Here
            '''
            Here File will upload on server through FTP.
            '''
        return file_
```

And also I don't want to save uploaded file, just wanting to use temporary uploaded local file and upload on FTP and the remove from local.

Comment: there is a path property. check the FieldFile class

Comment: @xfx, accessing `file_.path` also raising same error. "attribute has no file associated with it"

Comment: change the line "if file_ is not None:" to "if file_:", the file object is not none doesn't the actual file is not none, it's a wrapper class.

Comment: @xfx, already going inside condition. So, that don't preventing ahead...